# Using Jquery Cycle2 can I define a different slide effect for mobile?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I have a very nice responsive slideshow going, using the very nice jQuery Cycle2 plugin.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Now, in case of desktop use, I would like to use a subtle fade effect. I do this by setting these attributes on the container div:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides=".slide" data-cycle-swipe="true" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-auto-height="container" data-cycle-fx="fade">
```

But then on mobile devices, since my slider is swipe-enabled, I would like to use `scrollHorz` (horizontally scrolling), since this makes much better sense when swiping.

Is this possible? Here's the link to the API reference:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the HTML tag `data-cycle-fx` should be set before initializing jQuery Cycle, and I am using PHP, I looked into determining the user device server side.

I've found `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to be fairly reliable (I've heard it's not 100% foolproof, but in my case that's not a problem).

I created a function, from the example here:
[Using Modernizr to test for tablet and mobile - Opinions wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928200/using-modernizr-to-test-for-tablet-and-mobile-opinions-wanted) (hopefully, this is not too resource intensive).

```
function is_mobile() {
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

Then, in my slider HTML, I do the following construction:

```
echo '<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides=".slide"  data-cycle-fx="'.( is_mobile() ? 'scrollHorz' : 'fade' ).'">';
```

It seems to work for me. I am interested to see other examples or better practices.