# How can I redirect Desktop Users to one site and Mobile Users to another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, desktop

I would like that if a desktop user visits my site they are redirected to example.com and mobile users are redirected to m.example.com, I have been told to use this script:

```
<script>

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) { 
return window.location.assign("m.example.com"); 
} else { 
return window.location.assign("example.com"); 
} 
} 
</script>
```

but when I visit my site all I get is a white screen.
Is there something wrong with this script? and do I need another script, that handles the user agent or is it all handled by the above script?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928200/using-modernizr-to-test-for-tablet-and-mobile-opinions-wanted

Comment: Excess closing bracket? And add `http://` to url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>

if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) { 
    window.location.assign("http://m.example.com"); 
} else { 
    window.location.assign("http://example.com"); 
} 

</script>
```